# How to prevent Matlab from GPU switching?

Tags: gpu

MATLAB 2014a always uses the discrete GPU only, which is not necessary. (2013a didn't do this, therefore I think there might be an easy solution.)

How could I prevent this? I tried setting the NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching flag in Info.plist, but this didn't help.

I don't want to force it using gfxcardstatus as I often work with an external monitor.

Answer (score -1):

Disable automatic graphics switching in the Energy Preferences Panel of System Preferences. This will force your MBP to only use the dedicated GPU, not the discrete GPU.

Comment: Other way around...Forces your MBP to use the discrete GPU at all times.

Comment: Obviously, @njboot, I am not perfect, but I work for the forces of good. I do not understand what you are trying to do by spreading this misinformation. Disabling graphics switching forces the use of the dedicated Intel-GPU only.

Comment: sorry pal, you are wrong. "When automatic graphic switching is disabled, your computer will use high performance graphics. This may decrease battery life." I unchecked automatic graphics switching and my computer immediately switched from the integrated to discrete - as indicated by gfxstatus. http://postimg.org/image/6fq6hra59/